# Error while decoding base64 image string into an image file

Tags: java, base64

I have a base64 encoded string which i got from front end. Now i want to export that image string to an image file but it is not happening. Here, Can you tell me what i might be doing wrong?

`dataURL` is of the format `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA..."`. I have used all three ways but I am getting error in all three of them.

```
public void ZSC_ExportDataURLasImage(String dataURL,String fileType,String filePath) throws IOException
{
//      byte[] imagedata = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(",") + 1));
//      byte[] imagedata = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(",") + 1));
    byte[] imagedata = Base64.decodeBase64(dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(",") + 1));
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imagedata));
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, fileType, new File(filePath));

}
```

Error I am getting is

```
 Error reading PNG image data
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.zscore.utils.ZSC_DataExporter.ZSC_ExportDataURLasImage(ZSC_DataExporter.java:20)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Make an HTML file with `"<src img=\"" + dataURL + "\">"` so as to check the data. They are seemingly corrupt.

Comment: Could you please post the entire value of the base64 encoded string?